# How to prevent SeleniumJupiter from quit the driver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-jupiter

Selenium Jupiter run driver.quit() automatically after every test. But in some cases I would like to look at the browser after the test manually. In Selenium it's easy, don't call `driver.quit()`. But how does I can do that in Selenium Jupiter?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in the current implementation of Selenium Manager, since browsers are always disposed after each test. But you can introduce a custom wait after each test to manually inspect your browser, for instance, as follows:

```
@AfterEach
void teardown() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(60000);
}
```

Comment: Ok, I already use that solution. I thought maybe there is a annotation or something that helps.